# 3D LIDAR and Depth camera

Tags: lidar, depth, depth-image

I am using Ouster 3D-Lidar and depth cameras in a single robot.How can both be placed in a  robot to avoid any cross-talk interference?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics,* sidharth jeyabal. Can you link the datasheet for the depth camera you're using? I've done extensive work in multi-lidar environments and have never seen an issue with cross-talk; I don't *think* it would be an issue for you unless your camera is operating on the same wavelength as the lidar.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a definite answer because I don't know the exact model and method of the camera you use, but in general, in the case of a depth camera that calculates depth through Streo-camera, interference will not occur because it is independent of Lidar's method.

However, if you use a depth camera using the ToF method, there is a possibility of interference with lidar, but this is also a rare case.

Interference can occur if multiple identical sensors are used.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If it's a stereo camera, check your depth camera to see if it uses something like an IR grid or possibly IR illumination, and what its wavelength is. Not all cameras have this and you can turn it off in many cases if you don't need it. You might not need it if your camera isn't looking at featureless surfaces such as walls.
If it's the same as the wavelength of the lidar, you could potentially have some interference but that's not necessarily the case.

I'm not 100% sure about ToF cameras but looking at the wavelength should help.